# build.gradleの設定項目について

Tags: android, gradle

build.gradleの設定項目を一覧で出しているような公式リファレンスはございますか？

色々調べてみたのですがめぼしいページに辿り着かず…。

設定項目というのは、
`applicationIdSuffix`や`versionCode`のような項目の事です。

自身で調べた限りでは下記があったのですが、一覧で見れるページがあればご教授下さい。

- http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename
- https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#openActFromLib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

既にご存知だったら申し訳ないのですが、Gradle Plugin User Guideに記載があるかと思います。

- Gradle Plugin User Guide
  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide
- Manifest entries
  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manifest-entries
- Build Types
  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types